# Find whole line that contains word with php regular expressions

Tags: php, regex, line, preg-match-all

I want to search for a word "session" in a text. But I would like to retrieve the whole line in which this word appears. So far I have come up with this.

```
$pattern="[^\\n]*session[^\\n]*";
preg_match_all($pattern,$content, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
```

But I get an error "Unknown modifier '*'". Any ideas how to make such an regular expression?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your regular expression is missing delimiters, hence your error:

```
$pattern = "/[^\\n]*session[^\\n]*/";
// or, with single quotes, you don't need to escape \n
$pattern = '/[^\n]*session[^\n]*/';
```

If I interpret your intentions correctly, you're trying to match zero-or-more *not* newlines, followed by "session", followed by zero-or-more *not* newlines.

A simpler (potentially more correct) pattern would be this:

```
$pattern = '/^.*\bsession\b.*$/m';
```

That is, from the start of a line (`^`) match 0 or more of any character (`.*`), a word-boundary (`\b`), the word "session", another word boundary, another series of characters, and the end of the line (`$`), matching over multiple lines (`m` modifier).

You've sort of reinvented the anchors (`^` and `$`) with `[^\n]` which is somewhat non-obvious, but missed the word boundaries, which is probably not desired as you're matching [any word that *contains* the word "session"](http://www.scrabblefinder.com/contains/session/). That is, yours would match a line containing "sessions" or "possessions" or "obsessions" or "abcsessionxyz", where mine wouldn't; if this isn't desired, you can remove the `\b`'s yielding `/^.*session.*$/m` and our patterns will be more or less equivalent.

Here's a proof-of-concept, finding the entire middle line which contains the word:

```
<?php

$lines ="This is a test
of skipping the word obsessions but
finding the word session in a
bunch of lines of text";

$pattern = "/^.*\bsession\b.*$/m";

$matches = array();
preg_match($pattern, $lines, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

Output:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(29) "finding the word session in a"
}
```

Your pattern would have found the line "of skipping the word obsessions but".

Comment: Thanks, I have one question what is \b(boundary) really? It is not a white space, that much I know.

Comment: Word boundaries are described [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html), but basically anywhere between two characters where one is a word character (`[a-zA-Z0-9_]`) and one isn't. It's worth noting that our patterns aren't identical; yours will match "blahsessionblah", where mine won't.

Comment: @BorutFlis Updated my answer to demonstrate why word-boundaries are important.