# find a word in txt and show the line

Tags: java, string, class, if-statement, while-loop

I'm stuck with this exercise, I have to match the input of an user and a word on a txt file, and that match has to show the whole line, but I don't know how to do it, I have code but I am not sure if it is correct

```
//codes01.dat

IXE, Mangalore, India

BOM, Mumbai, India

PPP, Proserpine Queensland, Australia

RKT, Ras Al Khaimah, United Arab Emirates
```

---

Input: ProseRPine

Output: PPP, Proserpine Queensland, Australia

---

```
   import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class pruebas
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException
    {
        System.out.print(" enter airport name");
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = keyboard.nextLine();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("codes01.dat"));
        String s1;
        String s2;
        String strline;
        while (strline = br.readLine())
        {
            s1 = br.readLine();
            int numTokens = 0;
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s1);

            while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                s2 = st.nextToken();
                ++numTokens;

                if (s2.equalsIgnoreCase(input)) {
                    System.out.pritn(s1);
                } else {
                    System.out.print(" no data found ");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please format the code

Comment: Resolve the compiler error. The posted code won't compile.

Comment: Two br.readLine(). Would not be correct.

Comment: Wouldn't you need specify the delimiter?

Comment: is just put a word on input and then its gona appear the whole line of the word, if it's mangalore, then the output have to be..... IXE, Mangalore, India

Comment: your while loop should compare a boolean but it is assigning a boolean to string. there are two errors (beside other possible logical errors) 1.)you need to give a boolean in your _while_ something like _while (br.readLine())_ 2.) _System.out.pritn(s1)_ should be _System.out.println(s1)_

Comment: `(strline = br.readLine()) != null` this has to be in while loop. Remove second `br.readLine()`  Tokenize strline based on ,. use `contains() `method..

Answer (score 0):

Read each line from file, save it in String and check if `public boolean contains(CharSequence s)`

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried your code, but with understanding the requirement I can suggest you this example..
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14675452/find-whole-line-that-contains-word-with-php-regular-expressions](http://example%20in%20php+javascript%20with%20regex)

Use the follwing regex pattern `pattern = '/^.*\bsession\b.*$/m';` to match your string and see if that full line is retrieved

Answer (score 0):

You you use Java-8, you can elegantly solve this problem using [BufferedReader#lines](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#lines--).

```
BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("codes01.dat")));
String input= "ProseRPine";
String output= br.lines()
  .filter(e-> e.toLowerCase().contains(input.toLowerCase())).findFirst().get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are having 4 errors :

1) while loop condition should return **boolean**.

2) **FileNotFoundException** is not catched.use try catch block

3) **IOException** is not catched.use try catch block

4) `pritn()` method should be chaged to `print()`; instead of `print()` you can use `println()`

Your core logic is also fine, you just need to debug it. if you want you can use `String#contains()` method.

Answer (score -1):

```
 /* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import java.io.*;

import java.util.*;

class Ideone
{
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.io.IOException
{
String s1;
String s2="";
String input="Proserpine";
String strline;
   s1 = "PPP, Proserpine Queensland, Australia";
   int numTokens = 0;
   StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s1);

  while (st.hasMoreTokens())
  {
     s2 = st.nextToken();
     ++numTokens;
      if (s2.equalsIgnoreCase(input))
      {
      System.out.print(s1);
     break;
     }

  }
 } 
 }
```

Success time: 0.1 memory: 321344 signal:0PPP, Proserpine Queensland, Australia